# Internet connection lost after reboot

Tags: networking, internet

I have a Dell Precision T7910 with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS installed.

After I installed GeForce GTX 1080 Ti and nvidia-381 driver ( I had to disable secure boot ) , I found the internet connection lost after reboot.

I have two network connections, one to a cable modem/router, one to a network attached storage. While I don't have access to internet, I did have connection to the NAS and I can access files. I have fixed ip for internet connection but the setting hasn't changed.

If I unplug the cable and plug it back in, I would have my internet connection back. If I reboot, though, I would lose it again.

What could cause this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

What kind of ethernet/wifi adapter do you have? The symptom you describe is often associated with Qualcomm/Aetheros/Killer setups!

Comment: Both are Intel ethernet adapters. The thing is, it used to work without a problem previously..

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't know exactly why, setting internet configuration using `/etc/network/interfaces` solved the problem for me. Before, I configured network setting by clicking on the network icon on the desktop toolbar.

The configuration is pretty standard :

```
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
    address xx.xx.xx.xx
    netmask xx.xx.xx.xx
    gateway xx.xx.xx.xx
    dns-nameservers xx.xx.xx.xx
    up ethtool -s eth1 wol g
```